# GreenDao Foreign Keys set as null for ToMany relations by default

Tags: android, orm, android-sqlite, greendao

I am trying to model a `to-many relation between Users and Articles` using GreenDAO, where a `User has many Articles`.

**Reference:** [GreenDAO Documentation on Relations](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/)

My GreenDAO's generator code is as follows:

```
 Schema schema = new Schema(1, "com.example.greendao.models");
 schema.enableKeepSectionsByDefault();
 schema.setDefaultJavaPackageDao("com.example.greendao.dao");

 Entity user = schema.addEntity("User");
 user.addIdProperty().primaryKey();
 user.addStringProperty("name");

 Entity article = schema.addEntity("Article");
 article.addIdProperty().primaryKey().autoincrement();
 article.addStringProperty("title");
 article.addStringProperty("content");
 Property userId = article.addLongProperty("userId").notNull().getProperty();

 ToMany userToArticles = user.addToMany(article, userId);
 userToArticles.setName("articles");

 new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "app/src/main/java");
```

Next, I fetch the `Users` and `Articles` via `Retrofit`and convert it to `List<User>` using Gson

**Sample HTTP API Response**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Example Name 1",
    "articles": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Example Title 2",
        "content": "Example Content 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "title": "Example Title 10",
        "content": "Example Content 10"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Example Name 2",
    "articles": [
      {
        "id": 111,
        "title": "Example Title 111",
        "content": "Example Content 111"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

After conversion, I get a `List<User>` object where the states of the first user are:

- id: 1
- name: Example Name 1
- articles:
    first article
  - id: 2
  - title: Example Title 2
  - content: Example Content 2
  - userId: null
    second article
  - id: 2
  - title: Example Title 2
  - content: Example Content 2
  - userId: null

**And Here is how I am inserting my Users and Articles**

```
 daoSession.runInTx(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         for (User user : users) {
             userDao.insertOrReplaceInTx(user);
             articleDao.insertOrReplaceInTx(user.articles());
         }
     }
 });
```

**Problem:**

When the user is fetched using `UserDao`, and the articles are retrieved using `getArticles()` method, the correct articles are retrieved but the `userId` field in article is null (which makes sense since userId is null already)

Is there a way that upon insertion of articles in `ArticlesDAO`, the value of `userId` could be automatically set to the id of the user instead of manually setting it to the userId everytime in code?

**Note** The foreign key constraints have been set already

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
 daoSession.runInTx(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         for (User user : users) {
             userDao.insertOrReplaceInTx(user);
             for (Article article : user.getArticles()) {
                 article.setUser(user);
                 articleDao.insertOrReplaceInTx(article);
             }
         }
     }
 });
```

I know it could be prettier but, AFAIK, you have to set the user for every entity one by one.